# Calling depending Web Servcies

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a query regarding the call of multiple web services. The response of one service is getting pass as a request parameter into another service.

I have to call four web services in a queue. As per my knowledge, I can use NSOperation and add dependency onto another operation.

But can anyone suggest what is the best approach to call the web services in a chain?

Comment: GCD would be a perfect option for your requirement.

Comment: Use `dispatch_group_t`

Comment: I write a blog spot especially for this question. [Please read here with relevant code.](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2017/06/calling-depending-web-services.html)

Answer (score 0):

NSOperationQueue is the best solution for this. Use NSOperationQueue freely my friend